# How to share Html text to whatsapp intent

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I want to share `Html` text via `whatsapp intent`. The code I have written is below.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
                .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
                .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
                .toString()));
                this.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

**But whatsapp application is not showing in Intent chooser list.**

Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Comment: do you got it worked

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setPackage(com.whatsapp);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
    .toString()));
sendIntent.setType("text/html");
context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: I have initially tried with this code only, but I was getting below exception at the line sendIntent.setType("text/html");

    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

please change this in your code  and let me know if it helped you,

```
sendIntent.setType("*/*");
```

Answer (score -3):

You should use, e.g.

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://www.example.com
```

to open url in intent.