# Is there a way to share text to whatsapp as html

Tags: java, android, html

I'm trying to share a link to whatsapp as html so that the user will see text instead of the url itself like that.

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

I tried to do something like that so far however it sends it an empty message

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT,  Html.fromHtml("<a href =www.example.com/"+result+ " + > click here! </a> " ,0));

intent.setType("text/html");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<p>This is the text shared.</p>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));

Comment: it's gives me the same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share Html text to whatsapp intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076067/how-to-share-html-text-to-whatsapp-intent)

Comment: I have already checked that , this is not working on whatssap ,through it works on gmail