# How to share html content in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to share HTML content. But if I set the type as "text/html" it shows error as

> "cant send empty message"

```
    sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Referral Code");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"<a>url_here</a>");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share Html text to whatsapp intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076067/how-to-share-html-text-to-whatsapp-intent)

Comment: @grrigore No I would like to share the html text with several apps possible.